# Silently submit a job with qsub to SGE

Tags: qsub, sungridengine

I have a bash script which submits hundreds of jobs using `qsub` to a slowly responding SGE queue (it takes a good second for each job ID to show up).

In order to bypass this time consuming process and not kill my script when I quit my shell, I run my script as a background job by appending `&`. While this saves me a good half an hour at times, the job ID's still appear and mess up with the command prompt.

I was wondering if it is possible to suppress the display of job ID's or in some way silently submit jobs to a queue. Though, this [link](http://www.vub.ac.be/BFUCC/LSF/man/qsub.1.html) talks of a `-z` argument, it doesn't work nor is there a mention of it on the `qsub` man page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better solution: instead of using '&' use gnu screen to create a session, submit your job and leave the session: http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/ .

> Then, at any time, you can create new (full-screen) windows with other
>   programs in them (including more shells), kill the current window,
>   view a list of the active windows, turn output logging on and off,
>   copy text between windows, view the scrollback history, switch between
>   windows, etc. All windows run their programs completely independent of
>   each other. Programs continue to run when their window is currently
>   not visible and even when the whole screen session is detached from
>   the users terminal.

Comment: not the kind of answer that I expected...but a great solution instead. Having a lot of fun right now with [byobu](http://byobu.co/index.html) running on tmux...